# Binding a video file in isolated storage

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I am doing a windows 8 app having the following functionality. save the recorded video in isolated storage and show on list view(xaml). and play the videos by selecting from the list view. I can save and play the videos separately. but i have problem in binding the saved video files in isolated storage and show on list box. Can any one help me here please?

Answer (score 0):

Create an `ObservableCollection` that contains references to the video content models. When the application loads, read the list of files in a given `IsoStore` folder and populate the collection with the new models.